# Why do I need 6 backslashes to search one backslace with LIKE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

First, I know that searching with LIKE equals a double unescape for MySQL, this is why we need `\\\\` to LIKE one `\`.

```
mysql> SELECT '\\' LIKE '%\\\\%', '\\' LIKE '%\\\\\\%';
+--------------------+----------------------+
| '\\' LIKE '%\\\\%' | '\\' LIKE '%\\\\\\%' |
+--------------------+----------------------+
|                  0 |                    1 |
+--------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am expecting the first to be true, and the second to be false like this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/15404) show.
I don't understand why the results are as they are and **I don't know where to search** to find this out.

Does anyone have the explanation to this or hints for where to find it?

Comment: maybe interesting? [9.1.1 String Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html). Also, [Wildcards in the `LIKE` operator: expr LIKE pattern ESCAPE 'escape_char'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

Comment: The `escape` clause on the `like` operator may be useful. Here is some SQL that i put together to test the LIKE operator under various conditions. Alas, It is not as clear as it should be. [LIKE operator testing - Escaped and not](http://pastebin.com/KUNtCTEx).

Comment: @RyanVincent thank you, here is the result of the query: http://pastebin.com/J1p4se59 I'll have a look.

Comment: @RyanVincent looks like it's here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39808

Comment: Well spotted. That explains many things, At least we know about it now.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes. known and not fixed for 7years now... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a known MySQL bug.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39808